# T.RawValue Comparable in Swift is a raw deal?

Tags: swift, generics, comparable

With Xcode 8.2.1 and Swift 3, if I show the protocol definition for the `Error` protocol I see this in the generated header:

```
public protocol Error { }

extension Error { }

// at line 1250:
public func <<T where T.RawValue : Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool

public func ><T where T.RawValue : Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool

public func <=<T where T.RawValue : Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool

public func >=<T where T.RawValue : Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool
```

My question is about the operators  that appear immediately under the `extension Error { }`:

These operators *appear* to say that default implementations exist for types that have a `RawValue` subtype that is `Comparable`.

So I wrote some code in a playground to see if I could use these operators.  Here's the first attempt:

```
struct S<RawValue> {
    let v: RawValue
}

let s = S<Int>(v: 0)
let t = S<Int>(v: 1)

s < t  // error: Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'S<Int>' operands
```

In the `S` struct above, we have a `RawValue` subtype, and when instantiated as shown in variables `s` and `t` as `Int` the `RawValue` is comparable.  Yet `<` fails.

Here is attempt #2:

```
enum E: RawRepresentable {
    case value(Int)

    init(rawValue: Int) {
        self = .value(rawValue)
    }

    var rawValue: Int {
        switch self {
        case .value(let rawValue):
            return rawValue
        }
    }
}

let e = E.init(rawValue: 0)
let f = E.init(rawValue: 1)

e < f // error: Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'E' operands
```

Again, we have a `RawValue` type that is `Comparable`, but no joy.

So I guess I'm missing something fundamental here.  The Swift "Misc" header tells me that `Comparable` methods exist for `T where T.RawValue: Comparable`, but when I try to compare these sorts of `T`s it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume that it is [this method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1787197), but displayed incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. In Swift 3.1, those overloads show up in the generated header as:

```
public func <<T>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool where T : _SwiftNewtypeWrapper, T.RawValue : Comparable

public func ><T>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool where T : _SwiftNewtypeWrapper, T.RawValue : Comparable

public func <=<T>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool where T : _SwiftNewtypeWrapper, T.RawValue : Comparable

public func >=<T>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool where T : _SwiftNewtypeWrapper, T.RawValue : Comparable
```

which makes a lot more sense, as without constraining `T`, there's no knowing that it has a `RawValue`. So it just looks like a visual error in the pre-Swift 3.1 generated header.

`_SwiftNewtypeWrapper` is a protocol, which [according to its header](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/NewtypeWrapper.swift.gyb#L13), is:

> ```
> /// An implementation detail used to implement support importing
> /// (Objective-)C entities marked with the swift_newtype Clang
> /// attribute.
> public protocol _SwiftNewtypeWrapper : RawRepresentable { }
> ```

Therefore the overloads you see are used in order to define comparison operations on types that are bridged to Swift by being marked with the `swift_newtype` Clang attribute (for more info on this attribute, see [this article](http://modocache.io/swift-llvm-and-swift-clang)), where their `RawValue` is `Comparable`.

For example, the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef NSString* _Nonnull Foo __attribute__((swift_newtype(enum)));

static const Foo FooBar = @"bar";
static const Foo FooBaz = @"baz";
static const Foo FooQux = @"qux";
```

gets bridged to Swift as:

```
public struct Foo : RawRepresentable, _SwiftNewtypeWrapper, Equatable, Hashable, Comparable, _ObjectiveCBridgeable {

    public init(rawValue: String)

    public static let bar: Foo
    public static let baz: Foo
    public static let qux: Foo
}
```

and you are able to use the various comparison operators with instances of `Foo`:

```
func lessThan<T : _SwiftNewtypeWrapper>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool where T.RawValue : Comparable {
    return lhs < rhs
}

let b = Foo.bar
print(lessThan(lhs: b, rhs: b))
```

(although there appears to be some rough edges around this, for example attempting to use them directly yields an 'ambiguous use of' compiler error)

However, for 'pure Swift' code, the overloads you've found should bare no relevance. Swift types that conform to `RawRepresentable` with `Comparable` `RawValue`s don't automatically get `<` overloads or `Comparable` conformance – you have to implement that yourself.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help @par :)

Comment: Now, *after* seeing your analysis and example, I assume that `__attribute__((swift_newtype(enum)))` is what `NS_(EXTENSIBLE_)STRING_ENUM` from https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html use internally.

Comment: @MartinR Ah interesting, I hadn't even thought about that. From what I can tell, that does indeed appear to be the case (or at least, the bridging happens in the same way).

Comment: NS_STRING_ENUM  is (ultimately) defined as __attribute__((swift_wrapper(enum))), and swift_wrapper *seems* to be an alias for swift_newtype. Related: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0033-import-objc-constants.md.